# Yii uploading images

Tags: php, yii

In my web application I need to upload images while creating a record. But I am getting error although  I am following the instructions given in the yii forum 
This is the error I am getting .

```
Application Log
Timestamp   Level   Category    Message
16:50:00.207452 warning application 
Failed to set unsafe attribute "image" of "Vegetable".
in
/var/www/affm_web_v1r2_xxxx_untouched/protected/controllers/VegetableController.php
(29)
in /var/www/affm_web_v1r2_xxxxuntouched/index.php (7)
```

I am using dialog box for creating a new record.
My code for the controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Vegetable;
    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        $this->renderPartial('create', array('model'=>$model, 'asDialog'=>!empty($_GET['asDialog']),), false, true);
        Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl($_GET['returnUrl']);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
    else 
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Vegetable']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Vegetable'];
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->save())
            {
                $model->image->saveAs((Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/vegetables/').$model->image);
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            }
        //  $this->render('create', array('model'=>$model));

        } 
    }
```

My code for the view page

```
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
            'id'=>'vegetable-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
            'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    )); ?>
<p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'name',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>64)); ?>
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'code',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>64)); ?>
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'img_name',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>64)); ?>
<?php 
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image');
echo $form->fileField($model, 'image');
echo $form->error($model, 'image');
?>
<div class="form-actions">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'buttonType'=>'submit',
            'type'=>'primary',
            'label'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',
        )); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

I tried to change the attribute to safe but I am getting this error .

```
include(image.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Anybody help me how should I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you set the image as file in your model?

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'safe'=>true),
    );
}
```

in your controller change your line as

```
$model->image->saveAs(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/vegetables/'.$model->image);
```

Comment: Y I did. I have declared in model rules

Comment: and in your model did you set image variable public?  public $image;

Comment: I edited the answer. did you add 'safe'=>'true' in your model?

Comment: I added that but now ,when I click create Its directing to a blank page,Also I don't see the image in the folder. Also the record is also not added. Pls help

Comment: So check the folder permissions which you set as upload folder. chmod 777 -R youruploadfolder

Comment: no it does not help.Its the same , its showing blank page.

Comment: is there any file in your upload directory?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48476/discussion-between-user2492854-and-burhan-cetin)

Answer (score 0):

@Burhan  Cetin.I figured out finally. When we are uploading we should use

```
$model->image->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/vegetables/'.$model->image);
```

Since when we are uploading we should specify the full  path of our file(/var/www). We use  "baseUrl" , When we are rendering the images in  the view which already exist.